# Usage of likelihood ratio test for comparing 1 restricted pooled model with N models estimated separately for each group?

Tags: econometrics, likelihood-ratio

I have a question regarding the LR test when comparing one restricted model with models estimated separately for each group. Let's say I have the following linear model (mpooled) (with intercept):

```
l_WSalary=l_HrsWK
```

and I would like to find out whether there is a difference between 3 groups of people: Married, Divorced and Single. For this, I estimated the model for each group separately. Now I would like to somehow test whether those 3 models (msingle,mmaried,mdivorce) (each for the separate group) are in total statistically more significant than the pooled model.

I believe I could do it by using the LR test. Is it correct if I calculate the LR ratio in the following way or is it wrong?

```
LR=2([loglik(msingle)+loglik(mmarried)+loglik(mdivorced)]−loglik(mPooled))
DF=df(msingle)+df(mmaried)+df(mdivorced)-df(mPooled)
```

Regarding the DF I am correct that the result will be 6?

Comment: To find if the relation is different for three groups of people, create a single model with an interaction between between group and HrsWK. Then your LR test is simpler. You can also directly test the interaction term.

Comment: You are right that this approach is very neat and possible. I should have probably stated that this is a made-up example, on which I wanted to illustrate the issue and check whether my approach is theoretically correct or not. In reality, I have 12 groups and a large number of explanatory variables so interaction terms are hardly an option, unfortunately. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to test interactions as communicated in the comments, breaking up the model into different regressions also assumes the residual error variance is different by group. So you are not just testing whether the relation varies by group.

If you are satisfied with assuming different residual variances by group, then breaking up the model and summing up the log likelihoods is the correct approach to obtaining the log-likelihood.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. My model has heteroskedasticity even after log transformation and everything suggests that some groups have different residual variances compared to other groups. Thanks a lot.