# Can be any example of testing contrasts using Wald's approach reproduced with Likelihood Ratio testing?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

For illustration I will use R, but the question is general statistical question, totally not R related.

Assume I have a numerical variable and categorical variable with 3 levels, like A, B and C, for which I fit a liner model, `lm(value ~ variable)`.

By using the so called Wald's approach, I can test various hypotheses with this model.

By default:

```
(mean value of) A = 0: the intercept coefficient 
B - A = 0: the "B" coefficient (with respect to the intercept)
C - A = 0: the "C" coefficient (with respect to the intercept)
```

I can test each mean group separately:

```
A = 0: the intercept coefficient
B = 0: the intercept + "B" coefficient
C = 0: the intercept + "C" coefficient
```

I can specify also more complicated comparisons through contrasts:

```
"A - B = 0": `c(-1, 1, 0)`,
"A - C = 0": `c(-1, 0, 1)`, 
"B - C = 0": `c(0, -1, 1)`.
```

I can also test various combinations of the above:
"(A+B)/2 - C = 0": `c(1/2, 1/2, -1)`
and so on. I can complicate the contrasts in many ways.

I would like to know if the same is possible through the Likelihood Ratio approach? By comparing nested models I could test for each level, if only the factor is coded into separate variables on my own: `lm(value ~ 1 + level_B + level_C`. The summary of this model is identical, but now I can compare two models, like `value ~ 1 + B + C` vs. `value ~ 1 + C` to test level "B".

**Question**
But how to specify, for example, "A vs. B" or "(A+B)/2 vs C"? Or even more complicated contrasts (with more variables and more levels)?

I suspect, that, despite the well known weaknesses of the Wald approach to testing it can do more than Likelihood Ratio in terms of much more complex testing scenarios? Or am I wrong and the same can be smartly handled through comparing likelihoods of models?

Comment: The answer is “definitely yes”.  I hope someone will respond with the matrix formula needed to generate the design matrix with the constrast constraints imposed, so the the log likelihood of the proper reduced model can then be computed.

Comment: Thank you. I checked numerous sources, even asked the chat gpt, and it either says that "contrasts that are very or relatively simple via Wald's testing can be very complex under LR principle", "most statistical software prefers Wald's for simplicity provided the data size is not very small" and that "only nested models can be tested via LR, which complicates testing complex contrasts". I only found comparing simple levels, as mentioned :( This would explain why I see Wald method everywhere despite its bias at small samples and sensitivity to transformations, like in logistic regression...

Comment: Also found this, which comment section worries me, if I wanted to test interactions with LR rather than Wald's: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454240/usage-of-likelihood-ratio-test-for-comparing-1-restricted-pooled-model-with-n-mo?rq=1

Comment: @FrankHarrell I found this package as well. Maybe this will be interesting to you. It allows to test contrasts with LR provided the model is fit without the intercept, so we obtain separate coefficients per factor level. But this will work only for 1 factor, I guess, otherwise I will get full multicolinearity. So it seems Wald is still just easy-to-go when doing multiple-predictor contrast comparisons, and it account for within-subject variance in repeated-data models.

Comment: Someone who knows matrix algebra better than I can tell you the exact manipulation on the design matrix you need to compute to create exactly the submodel you need.  There is a 1-1 correspondence between a set of contrasts being set to zero and an alternative parameterization that enforces the same restriction.  I’ve been hoping to find that for a few years.  I’m sure someone knows.

Comment: Note that for standard contrasts such as chunk tests involving multiple degree of freedom interaction terms, or for combining main effects with interaction effects related to them, LR tests are automatically computed by the R `rms` package `anova.rms` function for common regression models.  It even computes tests for nonlinear interactions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the rms package. By testing interaction I meant exploring all related simple effects, like: "Sex: M Treatment: A vs. Sex: M Treatment: B" or "Time: T2 Method: A vs. Time: T5 Method: A" and more complex contrasts, rather than joint tests (these are obtainable easily).